# Mathematica package manager

Tags: packages, open-source

I want to bundle up a Mathematica package that I've written and distribute it as open source. It has a couple of dependencies that I'd like to automatically download independently from my package as well.

Is there any sort of established Mathematica [package manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) and package distribution site? (I'm thinking along the lines of pip for Python, gem for Ruby, nuget for .NET, hackage for Haskell, that sort of thing.)

I've seen [Wolfram MathSource](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/), and as near as I can tell its aim seems to be to collect various contributed packages from around the web into a central place, but it doesn't feel very active (maybe I'm wrong?).

Answer (score 27):

I'm not aware of any existing package manager. As to activity of Wolfram MathSource, let's ask Mathematica:

```
libraryLinks = 
  Select[
     Import[
         "http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?page=1;search_results=1;search_item_type=19&pages_count=100000", 
         "Hyperlinks"
     ], 
     StringMatchQ[#, RegularExpression[".*library.*"]] &
  ];

dates = 
   Function[{ll},
      Cases[Import[ll,"Data"], 
            _String?(StringMatchQ[#,DatePattern[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}]] &),
            Infinity]
      ] /@  libraryLinks // Flatten;

Histogram[(DateList /@ dates)[[All, 1]], {1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Indeed, it doesn't seem to be too busy lately.

Comment: Nice method/chart.  I wonder why the collapse.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard might have something to do with the launch of Wolfram Demonstrations. I believe that happened somewhere in 2006. There are now over 8000 demonstrations and only about 1800 MathSource entries.

Comment: Perhaps, but there used to be a lot of (re)usable packages posted to MathSource.  Demonstrations are neat, but hardly a substitute.

Comment: mr.wizard Agreed, but I imagine many of the package authors have moved over.

Comment: I thought everyone has moved to MSE? Seriously, there are many services these days which let users provide code in various ways which are much more convenient than MathSource (sourceforge,githup,google code,...). I guess that many package authors have moved to one of these. I would also wonder how many of the MathSource entries actually are packages, I think many of them are other "publications" e.g. notebooks used in talks etc., publishers of those also might have moved to other services (e.g. blogs,...)

Comment: @AlbertRetey True, there are many services available nowadays. It's a pity, though, that there is not one central depository of mma files. This makes the discovery process rather cumbersome.

Comment: Absolutely, it would be very good if such a central service would exist. If something is started now, I think it probably would need to be at least as good as existing services/repositories AND be readily availabe from Mathematica, like an app-store with search + public review + one click installation. WRI offered repositories based on svn a few years ago but I don't even know if that service still exists, it certainly wasn't attractive enough. An feature that would certainly attract me as a developer would be a distributed version control well suited for notebooks (=not line based) :-)

Answer (score 13):

This is not really a response, but a comment. I think that the collapse of MathSource could be because of GitHub. Almost half of the packages at  [PackageData.net](http://packagedata.net) are hosted there:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

data = Import["http://packagedata.net/index.php/api/packages", "JSON"];
domains = URLParse[#url, "Domain"] & /@ ToAssociations[data];
PieChart[
 Sort@Counts@domains,
 ChartLabels -> Placed[Automatic, "RadialCallout"],
 SectorOrigin -> 110 Degree,
 ImagePadding -> {{100, 0}, {0, 0}}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I really like the chart!:)

Answer (score 11):

Here's something that ought to handle many cases: https://paclets.github.io/PacletServer/

[[image]](https://paclets.github.io/PacletServer/)

It can handle one-line installation, gives a log of who changed what, and you can submit your own packages [via GitHub](https://github.com/paclets) so it's nicely integrated there.

This is in some sense still in beta, but without users there's not much space to see where exactly the dark corners are and what should be patched up.

---

Here's some info on how to add paclets copped from [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/adding-a-paclet-to-the-mathematica-paclet-server.html#main-content):

To show how to do that I'll add my  [Ems](https://github.com/b3m2a1/Ems) package that I showcased in my post [Making a Blog in 30 Minutes](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/making-a-blog-in-30-minutes.html). The first step is to install the interface paclet off the paclet server. To do this we'll go to [its page](https://paclets.github.io/PacletServer/publicpacletserver.html) and copy the installation instructions given there:

```
PacletInstall[
  "PublicPacletServer",
  "Site"->
    "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/PacletServer/master"
  ]

(*Out:*)
```

[image: post21-6722923238009970110]
<sub>(source: [wolframcloud.com](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/img/post21-6722923238009970110.png))</sub>

Now, we load this package

```
<<PublicPacletServer`
```

Then since Ems is already on my personal server I can just point the registration there:

```
PublicPacletServer["RegisterPaclet",
  <|
    "Name"->"Ems",
    "Author"->"b3m2a1 <b3m2a1@gmail.com>",
    "URL"->"http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer",
    "Update"->"DownloadOnce"
    |>
  ]

(*Out:*)
```

[image: post21-2385149726991367475]

If I wanted it to download from GitHub, since I already have it on my GitHub instead I could also have just done:

```
PublicPacletServer["RegisterPaclet", "Ems"]
```

Which would have done the same.

Now we can look at the [request that was made](https://github.com/paclets/PacletServer/issues/39) :

[image: post21-4494400686262893646]
<sub>(source: [wolframcloud.com](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/img/post21-4494400686262893646.png))</sub>

And that's basically all that needs to be done. At that point the ball is firmly in my court and I handle the small changes and the rest of the build process.

If you want to build the server yourself to add some features, feel free and just submit the changes as a GitHub pull request.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there any sort of established Mathematica package manager and
>   package distribution site?

[PackageData.net](http://packagedata.net/) is a free, open-source package distribution site. It is collaborative so that anyone can add packages and improve on existing entries. It could potentially have package management features in the future if it grows in popularity.

Answer (score 5):

At the Wolfram Technology Conference 2015 there was mention (at the keynote, if I recall correctly) of a *Wolfram App Store* that is in development.  This would allow people to sell or freely distribute packages, mobile apps, and CDFs developed with the Wolfram Language.  It was not stated how far out this service was.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't we make one? Here's a start -- feel free to try it at home :)

```
ClearAll[mfvonh, HelloWorld];
Import["http://mfvonh.me/mma/install", "Text"] // ToExpression;
mfvonh[Install, {"Testing", "HelloWorld"}];
HelloWorld[]
```

> Hello, world! -mfvonh

You can distribute any kind of content (definitions, data, docs, etc.) this way. Here's how it works:

I run a webserver at mfvonh.me, and /mma is just a directory containing whatever I need to transfer (text files with definitions, data, etc.). The "install" file looks like this:

```
Import["http://mfvonh.me/mma/install", "Text"]
```

=

```
ClearAll[mfvonh];
mfvonh[dir_, args___] :=
 Module[{
   BaseURI = "http://mfvonh.me/mma",
   ValidDirQ := MatchQ[dir, _Symbol],   
   ValidArgsQ = MatchQ[{args}, {} | {{__String} .., ___Rule}],
   FromMFVONH = Import[#, "Text"] &,
   Exec = ToExpression[#] &},
  Switch[dir,
    Install, 
    Exec /@ FromMFVONH /@ (StringJoin[Riffle[{BaseURI, ##}, "/"]] & @@@
         Cases[{args}, _List])
    ] /; ValidDirQ && ValidArgsQ
  ]
```

So in the example `{"Testing", "HellWorld"}` is resolved to the corresponding path on the server, which is also just a file:

```
Import["http://mfvonh.me/mma/Testing/HelloWorld", "Text"]
```

=

```
SetDelayed[HelloWorld[],Print["Hello, world! -mfvonh"]]
```

The simple way to define dependencies would be to include a reference to them in the install script, and a generic check to see if a package has already been loaded. It would be pretty easy to build out all the features of a decent package manager. Obviously executing code off the internet introduces some security considerations.

I would be willing to take this on as a project if people would use it.

Comment: Talk to Leonid in chat, he's been working on one.

Comment: I also have a start at http://github.com/mathematica-packages/mpg, and have been sort of waiting to see whether there was even enough interest in the idea to justify more effort. Starting to look like there might be enough interest for this to work. You use mine by saying `Import["https://j.mp/needs-mpg"]`, or if `Mpg` is already installed, by saying `Needs[Mpg``]`. It doesn't really do much yet, but I'm really proud of the bootstrap story.

Comment: @sblom If you have a chance would you please share [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49111/making-a-mathematica-package-manager)? Yours has some functionality that my prototype does not.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using just Github and custom package manager that keeps the stuff in the projects folder like npm

[LPM](https://github.com/JerryI/wl-localpackages)

It helps me a lot to collaborate and keep new version of all my paclets/packages without publishing them on wolfram.